# Issues with assignment operator and c-strings in C++

Tags: c++

Im making a class that is supposed to be able to assign c-strings the same way the string class i able to:

```
string a = "My string";
```

The issue I'm having is that it seams like it is not the `operator=( char operand )` that is used for this purpose. So my question is this: What is used instead?

What I have:

```
class exstring
{
    ...

    public:
    exstring& operator=( char* );

    ...
};

...

int main()
{
    exstring test = "test";
}
```

Which gives:

```
main.cpp:9:22: error: conversion from ‘const char [19]’ to non-scalar type ‘std::exstring’ requested
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not calling your `operator =` here.  You need to learn the difference between assignment and initialization.  What you're doing is initialization and you need a constructor that takes the parameter you're providing.  In other words:

```
extring test = "test";
```

Is exactly the same as:

```
extring test("test");
```

Except that in the latter case the constructor could be explicit, but not in the former.

Comment: `operator=` would still be wrong as it is taking a `char*` instead of a `const char*`.

Comment: It sounds like the constructor (not shown in example) needs to accept `const char*`

Comment: There's another difference. If the copy-constructor were private, but there were an accessible constructor taking `const char *` the first definition would fail. Technically, the first is equivalent to calling two constructors (optimizer may choose to omit one) - the second is direct initialization and is only one constructor call